# How to parse json data

Tags: android, json

I am very new in Using Getting JSON data from web, SO I am little confused here. How to get this JSON data in android: I am getting error in json fromat.

llike this in log cat.

```
02-16 21:31:25.093: W/System.err(22428): org.json.JSONException: Value {"3":{"ID":1172,"title":"dsfsdf"},"9":{"ID":1172,"title":"dsfsdf"},"8":{"ID":1172,"title":"dsfsdf"},"7":{"ID":1172,"title":"dsfsdf"},"6":{"ID":1172,"title":"dsfsdf"},"5":{"ID":1172,"title":"dsfsdf"},"4":{"ID":1172,"title":"dsfsdf"}} at data of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray
02-16 21:31:25.133: W/System.err(22428):    at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:100)
02-16 21:31:25.138: W/System.err(22428):    at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:548)
02-16 21:31:25.138: W/System.err(22428):    at auto.life.dashboard.LeftSideMenuController$MyPickAsyncTask.doInBackground(LeftSideMenuController.java:1807)
02-16 21:31:25.138: W/System.err(22428):    at auto.life.dashboard.LeftSideMenuController$MyPickAsyncTask.doInBackground(LeftSideMenuController.java:1)
02-16 21:31:25.138: W/System.err(22428):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
02-16 21:31:25.138: W/System.err(22428):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
02-16 21:31:25.138: W/System.err(22428):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
02-16 21:31:25.138: W/System.err(22428):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
02-16 21:31:25.138: W/System.err(22428):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
02-16 21:31:25.138: W/System.err(22428):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
02-16 21:31:25.138: W/System.err(22428):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
02-16 21:36:26.873: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(22428): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
02-16 21:36:26.873: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(22428): setComposingText on inactive InputConnection
02-16 21:36:26.873: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(22428): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
```

I have Json data like this fromat.

```
{
    "get": [],
    "post": {
        "_event": "mydatajson",
         "user_id": "12"
    },
    "data": {
        "3": {
            "ID": 1172,
            "title": "dsfsdf"
        },
        "4": {
            "ID": 1172,
            "title": "dsfsdf"
        },
        "5": {
            "ID": 1172,
            "title": "dsfsdf"
        },
        "6": {
            "ID": 1172,
            "title": "dsfsdf"
        },
        "7": {
            "ID": 1172,
            "title": "dsfsdf"
        },
        "8": {
            "ID": 1172,
            "title": "dsfsdf"
        },
        "9": {
            "ID": 1172,
            "title": "dsfsdf"
        }
    }
}
```

What i try to get data from java:

```
List<NameValuePair> mypickDetails=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        mypickDetails.add(new BasicNameValuePair("_event", event));

        mypickDetails.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_id", userID));


        HttpClient hc=new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpPost hp=new HttpPost(HttpPath.url);

        try {

            hp.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(mypickDetails));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response=hc.execute(hp);


            String result = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

           String jsontext = new String(result);


                //take object according to json format result                        

                JSONObject entries = new JSONObject(jsontext);

                JSONArray postListArray = entries.getJSONArray("data");

                for (int i = 0; i < postListArray.length(); i++) {
                    Log.d("Geting Value---", "+----"+postListArray.length());
                    JSONObject postListObj = postListArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    String myPickName = postListObj.getString("title");


                    DashboardVariables.mypickname.add(myPickName);




            }
```

Thank you advance.

Comment: The "data" field in your JSON *isn't* an array. The error is pretty clear.

Comment: maybe you should check out one of the many tutorials on the topic first, such as http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

```
 "data": {
```

`data` is not a `JSONArray`. Its a `JSONObject`.

But you have

```
 JSONArray postListArray = entries.getJSONArray("data"); // wrong
```

`{` represents a json object  node

`[` represents a json array node

```
"data": { // json object data
        "3": { // json object 3
            "ID": 1172,  // int 
            "title": "dsfsdf" // string
        }
```

Use

```
 JSONObject jb = (JSONObject)entries.getJSONObject("data");   
 JSONObject three = jb.getJSONObject("3");
 int id = three.getInt("ID");
 String title = three.getString("title");
```

Comment: I would also edit the answer to explain that JSONArrays are in brackets [], while dictionaries in curly brackets {}.

Comment: Yes, just the second when I did post this :)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
.getJSONObject("data")
```

instead because data is a JSON Object. JSON array start with []

Comment: You should also explain to the OP the reason why.

Answer (score 0):

The "data" field in your JSON holds an *object*, not an array. The error message is telling you that.

You may want to visit [json.org](http://www.json.org) to get a better understanding of the syntax and structure of a JSON object; `[]` is used to denote an array.

So rather than an array, you would need to get it as an object:

```
JSONObject dataObject = entries.getJSONObject("data");
```

Then if you wanted to iterate through the fields/objects in that object, you'd need to get the list of keys (fields) and get the object for each one:

```
for (String key : dataObject.keys())
{
    JSONObject postListObj = dataObject.getJSONObject(key);
    ...
}
```