# Reading data from JSON

Tags: java, json

Here is my JSON response

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "txn_17pHAkI4mX5ntfze4If5wIxW",
      "source": "tr_17pHAkI4mX5ntfzeIfNucubD",
      "amount": -100000,
      "currency": "usd",


    },
    {
      "id": "txn_17pH21I4mX5ntfzesrhdZwyf",
      "source": "tr_17pH21I4mX5ntfzeKLd0SWw0",
      "amount": -100000,

    },
    {
      "id": "txn_17pGVRI4mX5ntfzeBQPCWZZg",
      "source": "tr_17pGVRI4mX5ntfzegJNe1r4o",
      "amount": -100000,
      "currency": "usd"  
    }
  ],

  },
  "url": "/v1/balance/history",
  "count": null
}
```

I want to get "amount" and "id" from these three list. 
How to do it in java?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse json data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21824641/how-to-parse-json-data)

Comment: Basic question, already answered many times. Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

Look into [Google's Gson](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.google.code.gson%7Cgson%7C2.6.2%7Cjar).

You need to create a class that represents the json data.

```
class Response {
    class Data {
        public String id;
        public String source;
        public int amount;
        public String currency;
    }
    public Data[] data;
    public String url;
    public int count;
}
```

Then read the data into a variable.

```
String json = "your json here";
Gson gson = new Gson();
Response response = gson.fromJson(json, Response.class);
for(Data d : response.data) {
    System.out.println(d.id);
    System.out.println(d.amount);
}
```